# how to config the keyborad map of debian on mac air

Tags: air, debian

recently I installed debian 9.2.1 on my mac air 13（model a1466)

everything is ok except the keyboard has a little problem.

when I type the key[~](below the [esc]) in command line, the actal output is "<", I set the keyborad models to "Apple Laptop", seems no improvement..

So anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this [#162083](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/201711)

1. sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
2. add setting:options hid_apple fnmode=2
3. sudo update-initramfs -u
4. reboot